# Magento 2 - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry - Error in setup:upgrade after upgrade from community to enterprise

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento2

I upgraded to enterprise 2.3.5-p1 via composer.

Now I get this error after executing `bin/magento setup:upgrade`:

```
...
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessageStaging':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_GiftWrapping':
Unable to apply data patch Magento\GiftWrapping\Setup\Patch\Data\GiftOptionsAttributes for module Magento_GiftWrapping. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-Gift Options' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME', query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_group` (`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_name`, `sort_order`, `attribute_group_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I searched for **9-Gift Options** in phpMyAdmin's search function, but I get 0 results.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've gotten a similar error: ```Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes for module Magento_Catalog. 
        Original exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
        '3-Custom Design' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME', query was: 
        INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_group` (`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_name`, `sort_order`, `attribute_group_code`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)```
Seems there are some dead entries in database which have to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open the table "eav_attribute_group" in phpmyadmin. Then I selected "Structure" and looked at the "Indizes":

[image]

As you can see **EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME** is set to unique and is build with the columns **attribute_set_id** - **attribute_group_name**.

So I searched for the duplicate key and deleted it:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute_group` WHERE `attribute_set_id` = 9 AND `attribute_group_name` = "Gift Options"
```